# How to insert image in table

Tags: javascript, html, image

I need create a table with rows

> ID | Image | Info about image

and it's a part of code:

```js
function add(form) {
  table1 = getElementById('mytable');
  row1 = table1.insertRow(table1.rows.length);
  cell1 = row1.insertCell(row1.cell.length);
  cell1 = row1.rowIndex;
}
```

```html
<table id="mytable" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>picture</th>
    <th>info</th>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="info">
  <input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/png, image/jpeg">
  <input type="button" onclick="add(this.form)" value="Add" /> <br>
  <input type="button" onclick="del(this.form)" value="Delete" />
</form>
```

I coded only ID. Now I need to insert picture. And I don't know how to do it...

P.S: I'm beginner and doing a practice for college

Comment: Well to start with: 1) you don't have an element with id `mytable`. 2) You're not declaring your variables (`const/let`), 3) `getElementById` should be `document.getElementById`.

Comment: Please add your table to the html in your question.

Comment: I have it all, it's a part of code. Wait a second, I gonna add all the code

Comment: So, can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work this way, not tested though (and I smashed some other bugs in your function):

```
function add(form) {
  table1 = document.getElementById('mytable');
  row1 = table1.insertRow(table1.rows.length);
  cell1 = row1.insertCell(row1.cells.length);
  cell1 = row1.rowIndex;
  cell2 = row1.insertCell(row1.cells.length);
  let file = document.getElementsByName('pic')[0].files[0];
  let src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  let image = document.createElement('img');
  image.src = src;
  cell2.appendChild(image);
  // ...
}
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL

Comment: doesn't work :-(

Comment: OK, I edited the code, please try this one.

Answer (score 0):

One way of uploading an image using the image address would be the following:
You can try it using any image address from the web (e.g: https://static.thenounproject.com/png/802538-200.png)

In the case of using an image from the user's local disk you could get net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME due to security risks.

HTML

```
<table id="mytable" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>picture</th>
    <th>info</th>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<form>
  <label for="id">Id</label>
  <input type="text" name="id" id="id">

  <label for="pic">Picture Path</label>
 <input type="text" name="pic" id="pic">

  <label for="info">Info</label>  
  <input type="text" name="info" id="info">

  <input type="button" onclick="add(this.form)" value="Add" /> 
</form>
```

JS

```
    function add() {
  let table = document.getElementById('mytable');
  let row = table.insertRow(0);
  let cell0 = row.insertCell(0);
  let cell1 = row.insertCell(1);
  let cell2 = row.insertCell(2);

  let source = document.getElementById('pic').value;
  let img = document.createElement('img');
  img.setAttribute('src', source);

  cell0.innerHTML = document.getElementById('id').value;
  cell1.appendChild(img);
  cell2.innerHTML = document.getElementById('info').value;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).